# Wordpress: How to add active class to category attached to post

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add active class to category attached to post, here is my Code

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $current_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

    //for each category, show all posts
    $cat_args = array(
        'orderby'  => 'name',
        'order'    => 'ASC',
        'child_of' => 33
    );

    $categories = get_categories($cat_args);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        // $current_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id(),

        $args = array(
            'showposts'        => -1,
            'category__in'     => array($category->term_id),
            'caller_get_posts' => 1,    
        );

        $posts = get_posts($args);

        if ($posts) {
            //echo '<li'; if ($current_id == $post->ID) echo ' class="current"';  echo '>';

            echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>  ';
            echo '<ul>';
            // echo '<ul'; if ($current_id == $post->ID) echo ' class="current"';  echo '>';
            foreach($posts as $post) {
                setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li <?php if ($current_id == $post->ID) echo ' class="current"'; ?>><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
            } // foreach($posts
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</li>';
        } // if ($posts
    } // foreach($categories
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
```

This is my result:

- Categoryname class="active class should come here"

  - Postname class="current"

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: “Active” meaning, you are _on_ a single post page, and you want the category marked as active, if it contains that post? Then extract the post IDs from $posts using `array_column`, and then use `in_array` to check whether `$current_id` is among them.

Comment: yes, I want exactly that, can you please integrate that into my code??

Comment: Make an attempt yourself, report back if you run into problems.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately without success. Can you still help me?

Comment: Show what you tried then.

Comment: Can you check my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get array of categories assigned to the post. Then, inside the loop, check each element to see if it appears in the array.

The code should work.

```
<ul><?php
//
// get IDs of current post categories 
$curr_post_cats = get_the_category();
$cat_ids = wp_list_pluck($curr_post_cats, 'term_id');
//
// [your code...]
//
```

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
    //
    // check if "$category" is assigned to current post
    $css_class = '';
    if ( in_array( $category->term_id, $cat_ids )
        $css_class = 'class="current"';

    $args = array(
    //
    // [...]
    //
```

```
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    if ($posts) {
        echo "<li {$css_class} >";

        // echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ...
        //
        // rest of your code
        //
```

Comment: The code almost works, but now all "li" are marked as current. Categories from other posts may not be considered current. Could you please help me?

Comment: `get_the_category()` retrieves all categories assigned to a current post. Compare which categories are assigned to the post and which are marked as "current". It should match. If you want to highlight only one category (even if the post has multiple categories) add `$cat_ids = array_slice($cat_ids, 0, 1);` after `wp_list_pluck()`. (ref: [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), [wp_list_pluck](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/) )

Comment: Other categories (there are not assigned to the post) are unfortunately marked also as "current". What could be the reason? I implemented everything exactly as you wrote!

Comment: if ( in_array( $category->term_id, $cat_ids ));

somehow an unnecessary semicolon appeared at the end, after removing it, the code will work properly.  This solved my problem! Thank you very much :)